# cloduln't spot what is wrong with my reduce function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const str = "somethning"
const isParenComplete = (str) => (!str.split(“”).reduce((prev, char) => {

}, 0));
```

Why I have a unexpected token using reduce?

Comment: What are you looking to do here?

Comment: the body of the function does nothing and returns nothing so the end result will **always** be `!undefined` - which is `true`.. also use `""` or `''` - not `“”` - and lastly, you never execute `isParenComplete` anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing `" "` for `' '` fixed it for me